# How can I pull data from other websites and get it stored in my local database

Tags: php, mysql

I pull a data from other website by using curl but how to store in my local database.

```
$url = 'http://sample.com/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

I just want post some categories and sample of data.

Comment: Yes -- just parse the result of the returned data from curl and write it to your table(s).

The question is really vague, though. The more details you can post the better.

Comment: This sounds like a send-me-teh-codez question. All I see is a code example copy-pasted off the web. What have you done so far? We can help with a particular problem, but we can't write the system for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right.

well, i asume you're using mysql as database.
if you have allready set up your database including a table owning a blob or text formatted field you can easily store the data there by sending a query like:

`"INSERT INTO mytable SET curlData='".$data."';"`

with PHP you can connect to your DB via mysql_connect()
after selecting the desired database with mysql_select_db() you can start sending queries to the db.

use the mysql_connect() php-native-call to do so.

I hope i was helpful now ;-)

by the way, check out the [php-mysql](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysql.php) manual for further information.

Comment: While you have accurately listed the technologies s/he *could* use, you're also just repeating the tags s/he applied to the question. To gain up-votes you might want to say *how* s/he could use php-mysql to achieve this.

Comment: As I want insert only product name,price,image etc , how to sort it. Because $data gave   whole sitepage contents.

Comment: try to parse the data by searching i.e. css-ids or something where your desired content can be found in the answer-code. use regular expressions, to have performance or simply stristr().
it would be helpful if you come out with some details of your problem, because this problem has very many facetts ;-)